# Проблемы со считыванием русских букв

Tags: lazarus

В отладчике при считывании вместо русских букв вижу знаки вопросов Как исправить? [image: отладчик]

Код:

```
program project1;
uses
  RegExpr, crt, ConvUtils, Classes, Windows, SysUtils, LazUTF8, strutils;
type
  Births = record
    title:string;
    days:integer;
  end;

var
  filePath, line, text:string;
  txt:TextFile;
  i:integer;
  regex:TRegExpr;
  strList:TStringList;
begin
  SetConsoleCp(1251);
  SetConsoleOutputCp(1251);
  strList:=TStringList.Create;
  write('Path to file with dates: ');
  read(filePath);

  AssignFile(txt, filePath);
  Reset(txt);



  while not Eof(txt) do
  begin
    Readln(txt, line);
    writeln(line);
    strList.Add(line);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Файл в какой кодировке?

Comment: @zed windows1251